# SSH connection timed out from only one client

Tags: ssh

I'm facing problem with only one machine A which can't get connected to another remote machine B through ssh.

This is what I do when I try to connect with ssh from A to B :

```
ssh root@92.39.xxx.xxx -vvv
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 92.39.xxx.xxx [92.39.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 92.39.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 92.39.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

On the other hand, if I try to connect through SSH from a machine C to B, there is absolutely no problem at all. So I am sure the port 22 is open.

Moreover there is no public/private key set up beforehand.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Firewall, iptables, /etc/hosts.deny, fail2ban. Checked for the possibility of these things?

Comment: Also routing/netmasks.

Comment: @NickW I only checked iptables and /etc/hosts.deny. How could I check the others ? Cheers

Comment: @NickW +1 it was banned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll probably find an /etc/fail2ban directory.. glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of my problem.

`A` was banned on `B`, so I had to unban it with the following command :

```
iptables -D fail2ban-SSH -s the.i.p.banned -j DROP
```

Comment: I don't know enough about your setup, but I have used `pam_exec`, `ForceCommand` (in `sshd_config`) and also `sshrc` (the latter is weaker) to do the whitelisting after successful authentication. In my case whitelist entries also have a timeout (using IP sets), but this makes it rather flexible.